# stopping the script until a value is entred from keyboard in R

Tags: r

i have a script , and i want to start it with a keyboard input and then continue the work based on the value entered in this variable , i tried `y=readline("please enter a value")` but the script won't wait to enter a value , it just display this sentence and continue , how this can be done ???
thanks in advance ??

Comment: How are you running your script? `readline()` can only be used interactively. A reproducible example would help.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson: i'm running the script on windows , with 2 click on it (it runs in a cmd)  , thnx

Answer (score 6):

Here is a very simple `#!` script that creates a function `foo()` whose sole purpose is to echo back out it's argument `'bar'`.

```
#! /home/gavin/R/2.13-patched/build/bin/Rscript --vanilla
foo <- function(bar) {
    writeLines(paste("You supplied the following information:", bar))
}

## grab command arguments passed as -args
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)

## run foo
foo(args)
```

We grab any command line arguments passed to the script from the shell using the `commandArgs()` function, and then pass them to `foo()` with the last line of the script.

If we have that bit of code in file `foobar.R`, then we can pass in an argument and run the script using the `Rscript` interface. You also need to make the above executable (`chmod` it).

Then the script can be called like and works as follows:

```
[gavin@desktop ~]$ ./foobar.R Cl
You supplied the following information: Cl
```

But do note the information in `?Rscript` as unfortunately, standard Windows cmd shells don't know about `#!` like scripts, so you might need to install some other shell (the help suggests a Cygwin shell should work) to use the functionality I show.

**Update:** Using `source()` and `readline()`.

An alternative, if you can do without having to run non-interactively (i.e. you don't min opening the R GUI and running one line of code), is to just `source()` the script. For example, if this was in a script call `barfoo.R`:

```
dynamicwilcox <- function() {
    ANSWER <- readline("What column do you want to work on? ")
    if(ANSWER=="Ph") {
        writeLines("column was 'Ph'")
    } else if(ANSWER=="Cl") {
        writeLines("column was 'Cl'")
    } else {
        writeLines(paste("Sorry, we don't know what to do with column", ANSWER))
    }
    ANSWER ## return something
}

dynamicwilcox()
```

Then from the R Gui prompt, we could do:

```
R> source("barfoo.R")
What column do you want to work on? Cl
column was 'Cl'
```

or if you don't want to specify the full path do this:

```
R> source(file.choose())
```

`readline()` works just fine when used in an interactive R session and is really the best tool for the job - this is exactly what it was deigned to do.

The whole premise that you want to run a script in a batch mode but provide some input doesn't make much sense. R expects scripts to be self contained when run in batch mode. You might not realise it, but when you double click your script, it is being run in batch mode.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `scan()`, something like:

```
print("please enter a value")
y <- scan(file = "", what = "", nmax = 1)
```

`scan()` will wait for the user to enter and any text will be stored in `y` - a vector of mode character in this case.

Comment: @mdsumner: hello , it's not working , it's doing the same as the readline , it prints the sentence and then it write (read 0 line) and the script continue, btw i'm running the script on windows , with 2 click on it (it runs in a cmd) , thnx

Comment: As ever, and as Gavin Simpson offered with your original question, a complete description of what you are doing, what you are using to do that, what you expect to experience, and what you actually experience would be helpful. This is R code used interactively, as in typed into the R console. It also works if the code is source()d from a file.

Comment: @abd As I said - `readline()` is only available in an interactive session. You are running this in a non-interactive shell session. hence it **won't** work. I did say this in my earlier comment!!!

Comment: ok , how should i make it interactive?? and is there any other way to do this in my case??

Comment: Interactive means you have started an R session in a console or a GUI and can type commands into the session. You can run your script by copy/paste at the R prompt or by using `source()` to load and run a script from an external file. If I understand what you are doing, from an earlier comment above, you are running R in batch mode - this is designed to not require input from the user hence you can't run your script the way you are *and* have user input. An alternative would be to run the script using the RScript frontend, which can accept arguments from the command line.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson: ok i'll try this now

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu (not Windows) and found a solution.

Instead of `Rscript` use littler (`/usr/bin/r`) and make sure to pass the interactive flag `-i` to littler. This combination manages to convince `readline()` to work as desired in a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/r -vi

eprintf <- function(...) cat(sprintf(...), sep='', file=stderr())

prompt.read <- function(prompt="\n[hit enter to continue]: ") {
    eprintf("%s", prompt)
    invisible(readline())
}

ans <- prompt.read('Please enter a value: ')
eprintf("You have entered: '%s'\n", ans)

# rest of script comes here...
```

When I run it as a script, I get:

```
$ ./rl.r
Please enter a value: 42
You have entered: '42'

$ ./rl.r
Please enter a value: Hello to you!
You have entered: 'Hello to you!'
```

To install littler (on Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install littler
```