# Starting a second R script from within a parent script

Tags: r

I have about 5 scripts that are all part of a project to be run one after the other. I would like to open the first script, run it and then be prompted at the end, "Do you want to run XrefGenetic.r?" If yes, then XrefGenetic.r should open and run. I am 100% certain R can do this, in fact I think I used to know how but have forgotten and cannot find it anywhere.

How do I open another r script from within an r script?

Comment: I posted an answer with something similar in response to a Q a couple of weeks ago. Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507691/stopping-the-script-until-a-value-is-entred-from-keyboard-in-r/5522863#5522863

Answer (score 5):

Are you thinking of `source()` ?

My usual recommendation is to create a package, as that alleviates all these issues: functions and symbols are known (or hidden if you chose not to export them) and you have generally *much* better control.

Comment: What happens if I want to open the script in Rstudio or something such as that but not actually run it. In other words I would be sending a command to open the file but not actually run it.

Comment: It doesn't matter one bit what your editor or IDE is.  Either you run an R scipt, or you don't.  There is no intermediate step.

Comment: I think Dirk's comment should be added to the `fortunes` package