# Running R script_Readline and Scan does not pause for user input

Tags: r, input, rstudio

I have looked at other posts that appeared similar to this question but they have not helped me.  This may be just my ignorance of R. Thus I decided to sign up and make my first post on stack-overflow.

I am running an R-script and would like the user to decide either to use one of the two following loops.  The code to decide user input looks similar to the one below:

```
#Define the function
method.choice<-function() {
  Method.to.use<-readline("Please enter 'New' for new method and'Old' for old method: ")
    while(Method.to.use!="New" && Method.to.use!="Old"){ #Make sure selection is one of two inputs
      cat("You have not entered a valid input, try again", "\n")
      Method.to.use<-readline("Please enter 'New' for new method and 'Old' for old method: ")
      cat("You have selected", Method.to.use, "\n")
    }
  return(Method.to.use)
}

#Run the function
method.choice()
```

Then below this I have the two possible choices:

```
if(Method.to.use=="New") {
  for(i in 1:nrow(linelist)){...}
}

if(Method.to.use=="Old"){
  for(i in 1:nrow(linelist)){...}
}
```

My issue is, and what I have read from other posts, is that whether I use "readline", "scan" or "ask", R does not wait for my input.  Instead R will use the following lines as the input.

The only way I found that R would pause for input is if the code is all on the same line or if it is run line by line (instead of selecting all the code at once).  See example from gtools using "ask":

```
silly <- function()
{
 age <- ask("How old are you? ")
 age <- as.numeric(age)
 cat("In 10 years you will be", age+10, "years old!\n")
}
```

This runs with a pause:

```
silly(); paste("this is quite silly")
```

This does not wait for input:

```
silly() 
paste("this is quite silly")
```

Any guidance would be appreciated to ensure I can still run my entire script and have it pause at readline without continuing.  I am using R-studio and I have checked that interactive==TRUE.

The only other work-around I found is wrapping my entire script into one main function, which is not ideal for me.  This may require me to use <<- to write to my environment.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `method.choice` waits for user input when I source it in RStudio.

Comment: Does the script you source it into have any other lines following source()?

Comment: I see. Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5522863/1412059

Comment: I am not entirely sure this is working for me, or I am implementing the first solution wrong.  The second answer will follow the same problem that I have described above.  I will keep trying.

Comment: I'm not a believer in this mechanism for user input. If a function requires input (apart from data that is imported from file), I pass it as a parameter. If a user can't/shouldn't do that, it's time for solutions like [shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/).

Comment: Just wanted to clarify, you do not think taking user input in an R script is the best method? Could you expand on " I pass it as a parameter" for me please.  Also I have heard of "shiny" and will look into this if you think it will be useful for me in this context.  I just found this problem odd when I have never had an issue like this in my brief touches with Python.  Thank you!

Comment: Either you work interactively (and can specify function parameters) or you don't. If I expect a script to be used by users that are not familiar with R, I could use shiny or (if I need something quick and easy) I might use configuration files (usually I simply use CSV files, which my users can edit with Excel).