# Why the readline function doesn't prompt a line and store the given input

Tags: r, readline

I would like to let the user enter the dataframe propotion that will be used for training.I tried to use the `readline` function but it doesn't work in the code that I've written.How can I pass this value to the "train" object ?

```
dat <- read.table(text = " IndexRow TargetVar  chairs    tables     lamps  vases
                  1     0        0        0         7  9
                  2     0        0        1         1  6 
                  3     0        1        0         3  5 
                  4     0        1        1         7  8 
                  5     1        0        0         5  4
                  6     1        0        1         1  3 
                  7     1        1        0         0  7
                  8     1        1        1         6  6
                  9     0        0        0         8  9 
                  10    0        0        1         5  3
                  11    1        1        1         4  7 
                  12    0        0        1         2  8
                  13    1        0        0         9  2
                  ", header = TRUE) 

#function to Insert the data splits propotions:
readinteger <- function()
{ 
    tr_split <- readline(prompt="Enter an integer(0.1-0.99): ")
    return(as.integer(tr_split))
}
train<-dat[(1:round(nrow(dat)*(tr_split))),]
```

EDIT :

```
dat <- read.table(text = " IndexRow TargetVar  chairs    tables     lamps  vases
                  1     0        0        0         7  9
                  2     0        0        1         1  6 
                  3     0        1        0         3  5 
                  4     0        1        1         7  8 
                  5     1        0        0         5  4
                  6     1        0        1         1  3 
                  7     1        1        0         0  7
                  8     1        1        1         6  6
                  9     0        0        0         8  9 
                  10    0        0        1         5  3
                  11    1        1        1         4  7 
                  12    0        0        1         2  8
                  13    1        0        0         9  2
                  ", header = TRUE) 
train<-dat[1:round(nrow(dat)*(as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter an integer(1-9): "))/10)),]
dim(train)
```

The output and error that I get:

```
Enter an integer(1-9): dim(train)
Error in 1:round(nrow(dat) * (as.integer(readline(prompt = "Enter an integer(1-9): "))/10)) : 
  NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning message:
In `[.data.frame`(dat, 1:round(nrow(dat) * (as.integer(readline(prompt = "Enter an integer(1-9): "))/10)),  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: why the function ? : `x<-as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter an integer(0.1-0.99): "))` or `x<-scan(what=numeric(),n=1)`. If you want to use the function you got to call it : `tr_split<-readinteger()`

Comment: Hello @etienne, I tried the first suggetion and entered "0.8" as input ,It ran ok but I got 'x' value is "0"..What could be the problem?

Comment: because `as.integer(0.8)` is 0. Ask for a real integer and then divide the output by 10

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507691/stopping-the-script-until-a-value-is-entred-from-keyboard-in-r). you might need to use rscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this :

```
readinteger <- function(){ 
    as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter an integer(1-9): "))
}

train<-dat[1:round(nrow(dat)*(readinteger()/10)),]
```

Here is what that gives :

```
train<-dat[1:round(nrow(dat)*(readinteger()/10)),]
Enter an integer(1-9): 5
> train
  IndexRow TargetVar chairs tables lamps vases
1        1         0      0      0     7     9
2        2         0      0      1     1     6
3        3         0      1      0     3     5
4        4         0      1      1     7     8
5        5         1      0      0     5     4
6        6         1      0      1     1     3
```

or (if you want numbers between 0 and 1 as input) :

```
readnumeric <- function(){ 
    as.numeric(readline(prompt="Enter a percentage(0.1-0.9): "))
}

train<-dat[1:round(nrow(dat)*readnumeric()),]
```

Comment: A q regarding the code @etienne : If I use it in a block :
readinteger <- function(){ 
    as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter an integer(1-9): "))
}
train<-dat[1:round(nrow(dat)*(readinteger()/10)),] I get an error  as I don't get a chance to enter my Input.Why does it run to the last row of code without waiting to my Input

Comment: then it's best to put the function in the call of `train` : `train<-dat[1:round(nrow(dat)*(as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter an integer(1-9): "))/10)),] 
`

Comment: The problem still occurs: if I use it each part manually it works great (first running the "train<-.." and after inserting the value I run dim(train).But if I use it together  It doesn't let me insert the input:train<-dat[1:round(nrow(dat)*(as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter an integer(1-9): "))/10)),] .How can I force it take the value first and only than to go to the other lines of code? 
dim(train) # this will give an NA/NAN error.

Comment: if I launch `train<-dat[1:round(nrow(dat)*(as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter an integer(1-9): "))/10)),]` it doesn't return the problem. Can you post more code ?

Comment: ,I add it as an "EDIT:" on my original q.

Comment: I guess you indeed have to wait for the input before running the `dim`. Or you could try to check if `train` exists with a loop but the best way would probably to create a variable for the proportion you would to take, ask the user what he wants and then run the code.

Comment: from `?readline` : Thos can only be used in an interactive session

Comment: I checked If R runs interactivly and it is: interactive() [1] TRUE. So where does the problem laids?

Comment: I think you got to launch step by stp for an interactive session. If you launch all your code in one block it's not really interactive